# Getting ERROR in compiler_1.StaticSymbolResolver is not a constructor while building angular js app

Tags: angularjs

I am getting the following error when I am running ng build command:

> chunk {3} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.map (inline) 0 bytes [entry] [rende
>   red]
>   **ERROR in compiler_1.StaticSymbolResolver is not a constructor** "

My configuration is as follows :

```
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.24
node: 6.9.2
os: win32 x64
@angular/common: 2.3.1
@angular/compiler: 2.3.1
@angular/core: 2.3.1
@angular/forms: 2.3.1
@angular/http: 2.3.1
@angular/platform-browser: 2.3.1
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.3.1
@angular/router: 3.3.1
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.1
```

Please advise on what could the root cause be.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3727 this was caused for me by mismatched versions.

Ensure your configuration has the same libs and versions as below (it's the `package.json` `ng init` will generate):

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
  "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
  "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
  "@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",
  "@angular/http": "^2.3.1",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.1",
  "@angular/router": "^3.3.1",
  "core-js": "^2.4.1",
  "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
  "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
  "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",
  "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
  "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
  "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.24",
  "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
  "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
  "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
  "karma": "1.2.0",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
  "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
  "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
  "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
  "protractor": "~4.0.13",
  "ts-node": "1.2.1",
  "tslint": "^4.0.2",
  "typescript": "~2.0.3"
}
```